# Java: How to set context for ContextCompat in RecyclerView Adapter?

Tags: java, android

I found the solution but I still leave my question underneath.
I used `setBackgroundResource` instead of `ContextCompat`,
solution:

```
holder.mTextPar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_box);
```

Original question:

I need to set my item element backgrounds with ContextCompat, but I don't know what to put to the context

This I tried:

```
public Context context;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GameViewHolder holder, int position) {

  holder.mTextPar.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.border_box));
}
```

When I open the Activity where this GameAdapter "works", the app instantly crashes and error report prefer to this line where I have this `holder.mTextPar.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.border_box));`

Comment: Context contect declare global in adapter and use your '(context.getDrawable(GameAdapter.this, R.drawable.border_box));'

Comment: Take context as a parameter for the adapter and then use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All answers telling you to take context as a parameter is wrong or redundant, you already have a way of getting context from your view:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GameViewHolder holder, int position) {
  Context context = holder.itemView.getContext(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your adapter constructor , add context as parameter.

```
public Context context;

public YourAdapterClass(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GameViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mTextPar.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.border_box));
}
```

Comment: We are not saving it. We are just getting it from the view with whom we have set adapter. So it will automatically destroy if view will destroy.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what adapter you are talking about, `ArrayAdapter`, `RecyclerView` adapter; please mention it; also write more codes to help others understand what/where the context is needed. Generally if it's `RecyclerView` Adapter, the context will of views', e.g. `itemView.getContext()`, if it's `ArrayAdapter`, there's a `getContext()` method.